# Kotlin: How to notify backend connection worker threads of a change elsewhere in the system

Tags: kotlin, email, backend

I'm currently writing a backend server in Kotlin/JVM which has a lot in common with an e-mail server. It sits on top of a Postgres database and also uses local storage for files. Clients connect synchronously over TCP, and virtual threads are being used to maintain a 1-thread-per-client-connection setup. Each client is uniquely identified to the server and its identity is linked with the user's address. I have another pool of threads which receive and process messages from other servers.

How can I have the delivery threads (a) identify if there are any live client connections associated with a specific address and (b) notify them that they need to check for one or more incoming messages?

The one design I tried was a hash table of ConcurrentLinkedQueues, one per connection worker, but that doesn't seem very scalable.

Comment: check out java's `wait/notify` functionality